# creating nested loop with dict data type

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, statistics, nested-loops

I'm running a loop to calculate `abs(x-y)` for `n` trials

my code:

```
for i in P0:
     answer = (i['x']-i['y'])
     A = (abs(answer))
```

returns the values for `P0`

`P0` is the positions data for the first trial (`P0 = T0['positions']`).

Is there a way I can loop through all the positions (`Pn`) of all the trails (`Tn`) using a nested loop?

```
T type - list, of all the trails  
Tn type - dict of the 1st trial 

P type - list, of the positions (x,y) coordinates
Pn type - list
```

i tried:

```
for i in T:
       Ti = T[i]
       Pi = Ti['positions']
       for i in Pi: 
             answer = (i['x']-i['y'])
             A = (abs(answer))
```

but I get the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict.
```

Is there a way I can make this work as I'm not familiar with working with the dict data type

thanks

Comment: It is not very clear what you want, can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case `i` (the first one) is actually `Ti` you are searching for. try this:

```
for Ti in T:
   Pi = Ti['positions']
   for i in Pi: 
       answer = (i['x']-i['y'])
       A = (abs(answer))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving a detailed solution which is inefficient and funny but it will help a bit to understand how dictionary works.

```
abc_1 = {"ball":100, "bat":200}
abc_2 = {"green":10, "red":20}

key_1 = list(abc_1.keys())
key_2 = list(abc_2.keys())


for i in range (len(key_1)):
    print(abc_1[([key_1][0][i])] - abc_2[([key_2][0][i])])
```

The output is:

```
90
180
```